# Is There a Default Position on Beverage Refills?

Tags: united-states, washington, restaurants

This question was inspired by a 2014 case in South Carolina, where a man named Christopher Lewis was given a $525 ticket (later reduced to a warning) for refilling a drink at a VA Medical Center.

In Mr. Lewis' case, supposedly there were signs prominently displayed saying "No Free Refills." But the problem is that, in the vast majority of restaurants with self-serve drink fountains, there is no signage whatsoever about refills.

I know that normally you can't just take whatever you want for free, but I also feel like enough restaurants are fine with free refills that this could be considered standard practice in the industry.

Is there a default position on drink refills? Could you get in trouble for refilling if there is no signage?

Comment: Default is no free refills. When I grew up in the 70s in the US Mid-Atlantic, I don't recall it being common policy for free soda refills. Heck, self-serve soda fountains wasn't everywhere until maybe the 90s?

Comment: @pboss3010 when I was younger, there was no free refills.  The soda fountains were behind the counter unaccessible to customers.  Then they introduced free refills because self-service soda fountains reduces labor costs.  When they have self-service one-fill soda fountains, they are kind of using the honor system.